# Eclipse/LiClipse freezes when .py file is opened

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, freeze, liclipse

My LiClipse with PyDev started freezing several seconds after project is open. I've checked for updates without success. When it is freezed, LiClipse consumes about 48 percent of CPU and 300 000 kb of memory (consuming so much memory is probably ok).

EDIT: It freezes when the project is NOT RUNNING, it is just opened in Eclipse!

I've already tried to remove .metadata and import projects from scratch but this problem has occured again.

I've a suspection that this freezing occures when I have opened one specific py file where there are a very long strings (I'm handling with requests - posts).

Here is a piece of log from .metadata but It don't contains probably the issue of freezing according to time (last logged issue - 15:56, last freeze - 15:58):

```
!ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 4 4 2015-05-12 15:06:35.886
!MESSAGE No old model root?
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: No old model root?
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.log.Log.log(Log.java:36)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_ui.outline.BaseModel.setRoot(BaseModel.java:177)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_ui.outline.BaseModel$1$1.run(BaseModel.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
!SESSION 2015-05-12 15:24:11.565 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-05-12 15:24:16.605
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY com.google.eclipse.mechanic 4 0 2015-05-12 15:24:51.942
!MESSAGE Can't compute Mechanic Configuration directory: file:/C:/Program Files/Brainwy/LiClipse 1.4.0/
!STACK 0
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/Brainwy/LiClipse 1.4.0/
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.MechanicConfigurationVariableInitializer.initialize(MechanicConfigurationVariableInitializer.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.ContributedValueVariable.initialize(ContributedValueVariable.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.ContributedValueVariable.getValue(ContributedValueVariable.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.resolve(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.substitute(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.performStringSubstitution(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringVariableManager.performStringSubstitution(StringVariableManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringVariableManager.performStringSubstitution(StringVariableManager.java:358)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.VariableManagerStringParser.apply(VariableManagerStringParser.java:32)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.VariableManagerStringParser.apply(VariableManagerStringParser.java:1)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.ResourceTaskProviderParser.parse(ResourceTaskProviderParser.java:51)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.plugin.core.OldMechanicPreferences.getTaskProviders(OldMechanicPreferences.java:81)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.get(PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.java:29)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.collectTaskReferences(PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.java:43)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.ClassFileTaskScanner.scan(ClassFileTaskScanner.java:75)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.ResourceTaskScanner.scan(ResourceTaskScanner.java:40)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.RootTaskScanner.scan(RootTaskScanner.java:50)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.updateTasks(MechanicService.java:273)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.update(MechanicService.java:237)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.run(MechanicService.java:172)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.access$2(MechanicService.java:167)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService$ServiceJob.run(MechanicService.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-12 15:24:54.271
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-12 15:24:54.272
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Milwou'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2015-05-12 15:27:04.415 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-05-12 15:27:06.892
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY com.google.eclipse.mechanic 4 0 2015-05-12 15:27:19.466
!MESSAGE Can't compute Mechanic Configuration directory: file:/C:/Program Files/Brainwy/LiClipse 1.4.0/
!STACK 0
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/Brainwy/LiClipse 1.4.0/
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.MechanicConfigurationVariableInitializer.initialize(MechanicConfigurationVariableInitializer.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.ContributedValueVariable.initialize(ContributedValueVariable.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.ContributedValueVariable.getValue(ContributedValueVariable.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.resolve(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.substitute(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringSubstitutionEngine.performStringSubstitution(StringSubstitutionEngine.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringVariableManager.performStringSubstitution(StringVariableManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.variables.StringVariableManager.performStringSubstitution(StringVariableManager.java:358)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.VariableManagerStringParser.apply(VariableManagerStringParser.java:32)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.VariableManagerStringParser.apply(VariableManagerStringParser.java:1)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.ResourceTaskProviderParser.parse(ResourceTaskProviderParser.java:51)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.plugin.core.OldMechanicPreferences.getTaskProviders(OldMechanicPreferences.java:81)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.get(PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.java:29)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.collectTaskReferences(PreferenceResourceTaskProvider.java:43)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.ClassFileTaskScanner.scan(ClassFileTaskScanner.java:75)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.ResourceTaskScanner.scan(ResourceTaskScanner.java:40)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.internal.RootTaskScanner.scan(RootTaskScanner.java:50)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.updateTasks(MechanicService.java:273)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.update(MechanicService.java:237)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.run(MechanicService.java:172)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService.access$2(MechanicService.java:167)
    at com.google.eclipse.mechanic.MechanicService$ServiceJob.run(MechanicService.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-12 15:27:21.162
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-12 15:27:21.163
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Milwou'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 1 1 2015-05-12 15:56:40.907
!MESSAGE No existing console history at: C:\Users\Milwou\Documents\LiClipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console\history.py
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Milwou\Documents\LiClipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console\history.py (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.load(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:95)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.<init>(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:44)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.<clinit>(ScriptConsoleGlobalHistory.java:36)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ScriptConsoleHistory.<init>(ScriptConsoleHistory.java:56)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console.console.ui.ScriptConsole.<init>(ScriptConsole.java:183)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsole.<init>(PydevConsole.java:83)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevDebugConsole.<init>(PydevDebugConsole.java:29)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.createDebugConsole(PydevConsoleFactory.java:283)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.newconsole.PydevConsoleFactory.createDebugConsole(PydevConsoleFactory.java:258)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.console.PromptOverlay.<init>(PromptOverlay.java:71)
    at org.python.pydev.debug.console.PromptOverlayConsolePageParticipant.init(PromptOverlayConsolePageParticipant.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView$3.run(ConsoleView.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView.doCreatePage(ConsoleView.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.createPage(PageBookView.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partActivated(PageBookView.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView$4.run(ConsoleView.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.brainwy.liclipse.rcp.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the log doesn't seem to help much (the entries shown should be harmless).

I think you're right in that there's probably some pattern in the code which is making it recurse for some reason, so, if it's public, can you point me to it so that I can try to open it to reproduce/fix the error?

Otherwise, an alternative could be attaching some profiler to Eclipse when that happens and pass me the output from it (i.e.: https://www.yourkit.com/ can attach to a running program if you pass some vmargs to eclipse.ini -- https://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/agent.jsp)

Another option could be getting the Eclipse SDK, the PyDev source code (http://pydev.org/developers.html) and then do a debug session and press the debugger pause to see what may be happening...

Comment: Thank you Fabio for your response. I've uploaded the whole file including comments etc on pastebin. There are no other *.py files in the harmed project. Here you can find the code: http://pastebin.com/CCWei6tU

Comment: I may forgot to tell that the project is freezing when the file is NOT RUNNING. Nothing is running. The project is just opened.

Comment: This probably means that it happens when doing some indexing or code analysis... I think in this case, just the stack when it happens could be enough to diagnose it. See: http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-HowdoIReportaBUG%3F for how to get it -- note that you can use jvisualvm too (not only jconsole) to get it.

Comment: I've tried to put the long string into the file and load it when it is needed. It solved the problem. Thanks for advices, I will check the stack